# Signal redirecting

Tags: relay

I'm new at electronics and trying to do something for myself for USB and AUX

**1) 3 inputs, 1 output:**

I'll have 3 AUX inputs and want to switch to which input will redirect to output.

**2) 1 Input, 2 outputs:**

Most probably I can use same IC or something for this one too but wanted to give my scenario...

--

I already know how to use relays but most probably there is an IC for this kind of things... also; I have 3 computers and I'm also thinking about switching to HDMI signals with a single push button in this way (*if possible of course*).

Regards

Comment: *I'm new at electronics...do something ..USB / HDMI* I would not recommend that to a beginner because the chance that it will not work is very high. USB and HDMI carry are sensitive signals that need to be treated in a special way. There are so many "gotchas" and things you need to know before you can do this properly that you will fail. I suggest you start with something much simpler because this goal us unreachable for you and will frustrate you and you will stop trying to learn electronics. We all started simple and for good reasons. The USB/HDMI switch you want are for sale on Ebay btw.

Comment: Please edit the question to give more details what you want to do. What is AUX -- audio, video? What connector? How does USB come into play -- do you want to control the switching over USB? Or are you looking to switch with a physical button? It would also help if you make it more clear that 1 and 2 are two different scenarios that you want to solve.

Comment: Are you trying to recreate something like a KVM switch?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I'm software developer for 15 years and don't recommend me to blink led or something please :) New means for me i'm already doing PCB's but I don't know all component types. HDMI is not a must but usb or audio aux i want to to those. I already can do with relays but in that case I need to use too many relays.

Comment: @Tyler, kinda yes but my point is not simple change with that kind of device. I have 3 PC, I want to switch keyboard and mouse (2 different input) to one of this PCs for audio output and mic input is little bit hard to explain but if i can find a way for my aim except relay i can handle it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a [TS3USB221A](http://www.ti.com/product/TS3USB221A) or a [MAX4999](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/analog/analog-switches-multiplexers/MAX4999.html) will solve your problem. Any way you can search on Google for "*KVM switch IC*" and find several manufacturers of this type of IC.
For AUX you can use an analog multiplexer. [Maxim Integrated](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/analog/analog-switches-multiplexers/audio.html) has some of them special for audio.